# How to implicitly differentiate y with arcsin?

Tags: calculus

y = $sin^{-1}$ $4x^2$.

Is it $\frac{1}{sin}$ times 8x, for $\frac{8x}{sin}$?

Comment: No. Does it make any sense to write $\frac{8x}{\sin}$?

Comment: If you are being asked to *implicitly* differentiate, your equation probably reads 

$$\sin y = 4x^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Sin}^{-1}$ denotes the inverse sine--or arcsine--function. The derivative of arcsine is the following:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$$

In your case:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(4x^2)=\frac{8x}{\sqrt{1-16x^4}}$$

Also, one should note that this is a function in terms of $x$ and need not be differentiated implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

$$sin^{-1}(x)=\ arcsinx$$

Second we must find the derivative of arcsinx,

$$\ arcsinx=y$$

Set up a right triangle describing this.

$$x=\ siny$$

$$1=(\ cosy)y'$$

$$y'=\frac{1}{\ cosy}$$

Use your right triangle to get:

$$y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Now that you know the derivative of $arcsinx$, use it and the chain rule.